# Where Condition Case

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
SELECT shipment_line_id,
       Putaway 
FROM (
  SELECT rcv.shipment_line_id,
         NVL ( fnt.TITLE, ' 0 ' ) Putaway
  FROM 
         RCV_TRANSACTIONS rcv,
         RCV_SHIPMENT_HEADERS rcvh,
         FND_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS FND,
         FND_DOCUMENTS_TL  FNT
  WHERE 
         rcv.transaction_type IN ('DELIVER')
  and    rcvh.SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID = rcv.SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID
  and    fnd.DOCUMENT_ID = fnt.DOCUMENT_ID 
  and    fnt.LANGUAGE = 'US'
  and    TO_CHAR(fnd.PK1_VALUE) =  NVL ( TO_CHAR(rcvh.HEADER_INTERFACE_ID) ,= TO_CHAR(rcv.INTERFACE_TRANSACTION_ID  )
```

I would like if fnd.PK1_VALUE = rcvh.header_interface_id return fnd.pk1_value
and if not return fnd.PK1_VALUE = rcv.INTERFACE_TRANSACTION_ID IN This I cannot retrieve that

Comment: You have syntax errors including as extra `=` inside the `NVL` and a missing `)` for the outer query.

Comment: Do you really need to use `TO_CHAR` on all three values?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking here can be solved using `DECODE`.  Here is the condition you can use:

```sql
AND DECODE(TO_CHAR(fnd.pk1_value), 
           TO_CHAR(rcvh.header_interface_id), 1,
           TO_CHAR(rcv.interface_transaction_id), 1,
           0) = 1
```